# Minimal assumptions such that the solution of Poisson equation is $C^2$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Take a weak solution $u$ of the Poisson equation on $\mathbb{R}^d$
$$ \Delta u = f $$
By standard elliptic regularity theory we have (for some $\alpha\in (0,1]$) $f\in C^{0, \alpha}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, then $u \in C^{2, \alpha}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Now my (naive) question is:

> Are there some weaker assumptions that on $f$ that ensure that $u \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

By weaker assumptions I mean something like $f\in C^0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ plus some condition which is not of Hölder type (I am aware that $f\in C^0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is not sufficient).

Comment: There is a standard counterexample that shows the existence of $f \in C^0$ such that $u\not\in C^2$ (which I guess you are aware of); so I guess you are looking for an assumption of the form $C^0$ + "something not measured on the Holder scale"?

Comment: @WillieWong Exactly. I will edit such that it becomes more transparent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Dini continuity* may be what you are looking for: if $f = \Delta u$ is Dini continuous, that is, $$\int_0^1 \frac{\omega_f(t)}{t} \, dt < \infty,$$ then $u$ is $C^2$. This is a rather old result, but I do not know the reference. A quick Google search leads to [*Poisson's equation*](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math580f13/poisson.pdf) by T. Gantumur, see Theorem 42 and Corollary 43 there.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.

Comment: Additional references: the Laplacian version seems to have been due to [Shapiro](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=390550), and there is a version with more general elliptic operators due to [Burch](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=521856).

Comment: @WillieWong: Interesting, thanks! (I learned about the result from a colleague of mine. When I meet him, I will ask if he knows any relevant references.)

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: and I learned about the result from you :-)  I just looked up the keywords on MathSciNet for those references.